# Using IIS URL Rewrite in conjunction with SQL server to verify security on static content

Tags: sql-server, security, iis, coldfusion, url-rewrite-module

I am working on a project where I need to prevent access to static content on a windows server running IIS 7.5 and ColdFusion.

I already have an authentication system build with ColdFusion to handle logging in a user. The  difficulty is ColdFusion is unable to provide any processing on files that are not handled by the ColdFusion server.

My thought was to utilize IIS URL Rewrite and my ColdFusion system to do the following:

- User logs in with their Username and Password
- Upon successful log in, a database record is created with a unique random key and date identifying a valid session
- The last part of the log in process is to write a cookie with the random key created in the previous step

With the cookie and authenticated session now established my thoughts on how IIS URL Rewrite would prevent access to static content:

- Request is sent for a protected file
- IIS URL Rewrite will take the passed cookie value and send a request to the database table
- If the database reports that the unique key from the cookie is a valid session the request is allowed to continue. If the cookie value returns from the database is invalid, the file is redirected the a 403 response.

I have read some documentation (http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module) that shows you can do database queries with the IIS URL Rewrite module.

My main question is if this is a viable solution to protect content from being hosted when a user has not been authenticated as a user? If so, I have been hard pressed to find any examples of this online.

I appreciate any insight in the validity or stupidity of this potential solution.

Cheers!

Comment: What type of content do you need to protect? PDFs, images, etc? And how much material is there?

Comment: I am looking at protecting pdf, images, and flash based content. There is quite a bit of content. Probably exceeding 40GB with an unlimited ceiling.